# How to indent addressee on scrlttr2

Tags: scrlttr2

I'm using the `scrlttr2` class to typeset an Italian letter. My problem is that the addressee stays on the right side of the letter. An Italian letter has that address on the left, and name and surname, city address reside in different lines. The two or more lines are aligned and a simple letter (like DA:; A:; e p.c.) are before the address.

Can I obtain this without a table? In programs like word, I obtain this using margin and tab. Is there something similar (in LaTeX)?

What I need is kind of this:

> ```
>                  DA: Destination name
>                       street, red tortke, 123
>                       new york
> ```
>
> Subject: this is the subject....
>
> this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text this is the body of text
>
> ```
>                                        signature
>                                    xyz xyz xyz xyz
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the address to the right, it seems that you have chosen the wrong LCO (for Swizz' letters). Try this simple template and start working from this one. The Komascript manual is a little bit cryptic, but the different options is well described on page 136 ff.

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% An alternative to the standard LaTeX letter class.

\documentclass{scrlttr2}

% Don't forget to read the KOMA-Script documentation, scrguien.pdf

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Nomen Nescio \\ Gladiator} % your name and title
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Colosseum \\ Rome \\ Italy}

\setkomavar{signature}{Nomen Nescio} % printed after the \closing
\renewcommand{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright} % make the signature ragged right

\setkomavar{subject}{} % subject of the letter

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Emperor Cæsar \\ HQ Roman Empire \\ Rome \\ Italy}

\opening{Hello Cæsar}  % eg. Hello

Aut Cæsar aut nihil. Errare humanum est!

\closing{Best regards} %eg. Regards

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this class for french letters and solved the same problem by using the `NF.lco` or the `NFpro.lco` file.

Call them in your `mweletter.tex` file with `\LoadLetterOption{NF}` in your preamble. Refer to the KOMA-Script documentation for more details.

Comment: Hi and welcome, can you give us a hint where we can find `NFpro.lco`?

Comment: It is part of the KOMA scrpt package IIRW... (sorry for nor seeing your questoin earlier ! )